# Как сделать задний темно-зеленый как на фото и закрепить его там?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Хотел бы спросить у вас - как сделать задний темно-зеленый блок как на фото и закрепить его, то есть чтобы н оставался там же при сужение екрана?

[image: фото самого блока и изображения из фигмы]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сделать так..

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.picture {
  background: 0 0 / cover url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDYHa.jpg');
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  border: solid #5EAADF 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.picture:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #254D4D;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="picture"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное вам за помощь и за этот способ. Хорошего вам дня)

Comment: @Maksim_432 Спасибо! И тебе хорошего дня :) Если будешь использовать способ выше, то стоит отметить его как правильный т.е. галочку поставить на том варианте.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так, как один из способов:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.containet {
  display: grid;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.containet>img {
  width: 200px;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="containet">
  <div class="circle"></div><img src="https://funart.pro/uploads/posts/2021-04/1618405484_27-funart_pro-p-milie-detki-deti-krasivo-foto-29.jpg" alt="Girl">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, буду использовать этот способ!